# How to run executable within the tcl?

Tags: tcl

I am trying to execute program which has some options, and take as an input txt file. So I have try this:

```
set myExecutable [file join $::env(path_to_the_program) bin executable_name] 
if { ![file exists $myExecutable ] } {
puts "error"
}

if { ![file executable $myExecutable ] } {
puts "error"
}


set arguments [list -option1 -option2]
set status [catch { exec $myExecutable $arguments  $txtFileName } output]
if { $status != 0 } {
    puts "output = $output"
}
```

So it's print:

```
output = Usage: executable_name -option1 -option2 <txt_file_name>
child process exited abnormally
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't actually provide the arguments to you executable. Just the textFileName. Try:

```
set status [catch {exec $myExecutable -option1 -option2 $txtFileName} output]
```

or if you prefer to keep the arguments in a list:

```
set status [catch {exec $myExecutable {*}$arguments} output]
```

where the {*} syntax will cause the list to be expanded in place. In Tcl versions before this was added (8.5) you would use:

```
set status [catch {eval exec [list $myExecutable] $arguments} output]
```

where the eval command unwraps the lists so that exec sees a single set of arguments. Adding the extra [list] statement around your $myExecutable protects it's contents against being treated as a list by the interpreter pass.